# Should it be "clotted cream scones" or "clotted-cream scones"?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, compounds, attributive-nouns, compound-adjectives

> I'm eating clotted cream-covered scones.

or

> I'm eating clotted-cream-covered scones.

or

> I'm eating clotted cream covered scones.

Formally, I thought they'd have to be ***clotted-cream*** scones, but Grammarly insists they're merely ***clotted cream*** scones.

I thought a compound adjective should be hyphenated when it appears before the noun it modifies, but it looks like I'm wrong.

Can anyone tell me what the rule is here, please?

Comment: This is a general reference question. The *Chicago Manual of Style* has a multipage [pdf download](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/images/ch07_tab01.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi6u8GWkO3SAhXF7IMKHTHpAoYQFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNGf7dAsS9s7l_SzNIygq97K3JuPJw&sig2=YmaLOzCleH7dYO_r_FAb0A) that summarizes and exemplifies its guidelines.

Comment: Your quoted sentenced differ from the rest of your text. The quotes include 'covered', the rest doesn't. This makes the question confusing. For what it's worth,I'd expect a 'clotted cream scone' to have clotted cream included in the recipe as an ingredient.if I was talking about a scone to which clotted cream had been applied I'd probably say I was 'eating a scone and clotted cream. A similar problem arises with distinguishing between a sausage roll and a 'roll and sausage'.

Comment: It's a rather specific question as far as I can see.I don't see any confusion. My quoted sentence was alluding to whether they're strictly "clotted-cream" scones or "clotted cream" scones. If they're the former, surely then they must also be "clotted-cream-covered" scones; if it's the latter, however, then they must be "". I'm not sure where you're from, but

Comment: This has been addressed here before. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier) has:  "Major style guides advise consulting a dictionary to determine whether a compound adjective should be hyphenated; compounds entered as dictionary headwords are permanent compounds, and for these, the dictionary's hyphenation should be followed even when the compound adjective precedes a noun. According to some guides, hyphens are unnecessary in familiar compounds used as ...

Comment: adjectives 'where no ambiguity could result', while other guides suggest using hyphens 'generally' in such compounds used as adjectives before nouns." // As clotted [cream scones] doesn't make sense, and as nobody on the internet seems to use a hyphen, _clotted cream scones_ is the natural choice and the first set of style guides Wikipedia mentions the ones actually looking at what Anglophones choose to do.

Comment: It's not a compound adjective, but a compound noun (assuming it is a compound word in the first place!)